# Chess board squares counting

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Let a chess board is a $(8*8)$ grid. How many squares are there?

I have tried it manually. After some time I lost count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of squares $= x$

We know that, $1^2+2^2+.......+n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$

$x=1^2+2^2+.......+8^2$
$=8(8+1)(2*8+1)/6$
$=204$

So, number of total squares $= 204$

Answer (score 5):

There are $8 \times 8=64$ squares of the size $1 \times 1$, $7 \times 7=49$ squares of the size $2 \times 2$, and so on. So the answer is $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \dots + 8^2$ which equals $204$.